# class relations and site architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a asp.net web site
i build a class localiziedpage  that inherit from System.Web.UI.Page this class in dealing with all localization of the page.  ii have a class basepage that inherit from localiziedpage  that get all simple data from db for a page (h1,title,main content,description...)

now i need to create a page that bring another type of data (news list,albums ...)
do i need to build a separate class for every type of page?

for rss page a rssPage class that inherit from basePage  ?
for newslist page a newsListPage that inherit from basePage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally only use a base page in ASP.NET webforms where you want to share common functionality across a number of pages. If every page on your site has to deal with localised information then it probably makes sense to use a base page here. However, things like news listings will only exist one a certain pages, so there is no reason to use a base class.

Instead you would build the actual functionality for these pages using classes in a class library that are then referenced from using statements in the page. So for a news listing page you might have classes that fetch data from the database, then a class that represents a single news item with methods that bring back collections of news items, say as a `List<NewsItem>`.

In your page you might then have an `ObjectDataSource` that is bound to your `List<NewsItem>` and rendered via an `asp:Repeater` control in your .aspx declarative code.

Comment: ok, so i need to create a class that will have functionally just for newsItem , newsList.
and other one for another type of data (events)?

Comment: Yes, but these don't need to inherit from the System.Web.UI.Page - they will be standard classes. I'd check out http://www.asp.net/web-forms/fundamentals for further reading.